# Code execution getContentPane?

Tags: java, swing, oop, jframe

```
frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.blue);
```

How is both method being called at a same time?  Does both method belong to `JFrame` class?

`getContentPane()` returns container, if it is executed first then it would be like this?

```
frame.Container.setBackground(Color.blue)
```

Is this known as dereferncing?

Just expalin me how does this code is executed step by step?

Comment: Please read [literally any beginning OOP tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code:

```
frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.blue);
```

1. **First executes `frame.getContentPane()`**

   the object referred by frame has a method called `getContentPane()`. It returns the contentPane object for this frame.
2. **then executes `setBackground(Color.blue)` part.**

   this method is inside the Container object that returned by the first part of the statement `(frame.getContentPane())`. It's setBackground(Color c) method (Inherited from Component Class ) sets the background which the parameter has (Color.blue).

You can't access the Container object using `frame.Container.` as it is not a pubic attribute in the frame object.

But you can do this way:

```
Container cont = frame.getContentPane();
cont.setBackground(Color.blue);
```

now `cont` variable refers to the Container object;

Answer (score 1):

getContentPane() return the container and when you are calling setBackground method it is executed using the container that was return by your previous method call